# datagridview position on cell

Tags: c#, vb.net, datagridview

By using the event
i have code

```
 Private Sub dgPredracunS_CellValueChanged(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgPredracunS.CellValueChanged

     _curRow= e.RowIndex  
     _curCell= e.ColumnIndex

       If dgPredracunS.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name = "Quant" Then
           If dgPredracunS.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("Quant").Value > 10 Then
               MsgBox("Enter new value")
               dgPredracunS.CurrentCell = dgPredracunS(_curRow, _curCell)
           End if
       End if
End Sub
```

i want to position on that cell so user can enter new value. Otherwise it should move through datagrid as it works now. But the main reason is that it wont focus on that cell.

I know about the event Validating but for some reason i cant do it because there is a lot more code on this event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original post is hard to understand, however from your comment to @jonathana correct answer…

> *“This was not solution for my problem main reason is on datagrid i have like 5 columns which are able to edit through datagrid so im
>   moving with key arrows through grid and editing cells. The main reason
>   is if i enter invalid value it should stop and focus again on that
>   cell”*

If I understand this correctly, the user is using the arrow keys to go to the next column after they have changed a value in the previous cell. This is doable however; the main reason in your comment may be a little more complicated than it appears. Your comment:

> *’The main reason is if i enter invalid value it should stop and focus again on that cell”*

To return to the previous cell AFTER a user has already pressed the arrow key, enter key, tab key or any other key, may be a challenge. The `DataGridView` control will move to this new location AFTER the `CellValidating` or `CellValueChanged` events are fired. Therefore, without knowing what “Key” the user pressed (right arrow, left arrow, up arrow,,, etc) it may be a challenge to figure out what the “previous” cell location was because the `DataGridView` control doesn’t know.

One possible solution would be to do as suggested above and capture each key pressed from the cells in the “Quant” column. This approach may be overkill; but this will allow you to capture the keys the user presses when changing a cells value. If the user tries to use the arrow keys when the value in the cell is invalid, you could pop up the message and ignore the arrow key pressed. Alternatively, not allow the user to enter invalid values. Check the value each time the user presses a key and if the value is over ten then popup a message and ignore the key pressed.

Following jonathana’s approach with some added error checks to capture bad numbers and ignore blank cells. The user will not be able to type values greater than 10 into the “Quant” columns cells and have them remain. If the user enters a value over 10 and tries to leave the cell, a message pops up, indicating the error, then simply ignores (CancelEdit) what the user entered, keeps the old value and finally lets the `DataGridView` control move on to the next cell. If the user enters characters (invalid numbers) then obviously a string comparison, against an integer value (10) is meaningless therefore as before… simply ignore the users input, keep the old value and allow the `DatagridGridView` control to move on to the next cell. Since this allows new rows to be added, there is the possibility the “Quant” cell could be blank and have no value. Therefore, blank values are allowed. Hope this helps.

```
Private Sub dgPredracunS_CellValidating(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs) Handles dgPredracunS.CellValidating
  Dim newValue As Integer
  Dim oldValue As String
  If dgPredracunS.Rows(e.RowIndex).IsNewRow Then Return
  If (Not (dgPredracunS.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name = "Quant")) Then Return

  If (dgPredracunS.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("Quant").Value IsNot Nothing) Then
    oldValue = dgPredracunS.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("Quant").Value
  Else
    oldValue = ""
  End If

  If (Int32.TryParse(e.FormattedValue.ToString(), newValue)) Then
    If newValue > 10 Then
      PrintErrorMessage("Can not be greater than 10: ", newValue.ToString(), oldValue, e.RowIndex, e.ColumnIndex)
    End If
  Else
    If Not e.FormattedValue = "" Then
      PrintErrorMessage("Not a valid number: ", e.FormattedValue, oldValue, e.RowIndex, e.ColumnIndex)
    End If
  End If
End Sub

Private Sub PrintErrorMessage(message As String, newValue As String, oldValue As String, row As Int32, col As Int32)
  MsgBox(message + newValue + " in cell row: " + row.ToString() + " Col: " + col.ToString() + Environment.NewLine() +
           "... Using old value: " + oldValue)
  dgPredracunS.CancelEdit()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `CellValidating` event and prompt the user with `ErrorText` property:

```
Private Sub dgPredracunS_CellValidating(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs) Handles dgPredracunS.CellValidating

        If dgPredracunS.Rows(e.RowIndex).IsNewRow Then Return
        If dgPredracunS.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name = "Quant" Then
        Me.dgPredracunS.Rows(e.RowIndex).ErrorText = ""
        If CType(e.FormattedValue.ToString(), Integer) > 10 Then
            e.Cancel = True
            Me.dgPredracunS.Rows(e.RowIndex).ErrorText = "the value is not valid"
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Hey @jonathana This was not solution for my problem main reason is on datagrid i have like 5 columns which are able to edit through datagrid so im moving with key arrows through grid and editing cells. The main reason is if i enter invalid value it should stop and focus again on that cell